# Unable to connect to local DB2 instance

Tags: db2, db2-luw, tcpip

I have installed an Enterprise version of DB2 on my local Windows 11 pro laptop for some development tasks.
Installation proceeded without errors but, it seems I cannot connect using TCP. If I try to stop/start from the admin console, it says I do not have set the environment variables even if I try to printout it works.

This is what I can see with db2set -all

```
C:\Windows\System32>db2set -all
[e] DB2PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB
[i] DB2INSTOWNER=LAPTOP-HBU9NEC4
[i] DB2PORTRANGE=20000:20005
[i] DB2INSTPROF=C:\PROGRAMDATA\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1
[i] DB2COMM=TCPIP
[g] DB2_EXTSECURITY=YES
[g] DB2_COMMON_APP_DATA_PATH=C:\ProgramData
[g] DB2SYSTEM=LAPTOP-HBU9NEC4
[g] DB2PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB
[g] DB2INSTDEF=DB2
[g] DB2ADMINSERVER=DB2DAS00
```

When I try to stop the DB I get

```
C:\> db2stop
SQL1390C  The environment variable DB2INSTANCE is not defined or is invalid.
```

I tried to print the DB2INSTACE and I get this:

```
C:\>echo %DB2INSTANCE%
DB2
```

This is what I get if I try to create a sample DB

```
C:\>db2 create database TEST001
SQL1032N  No start database manager command was issued.  SQLSTATE=57019
```

Any clue?
Thanks

Comment: One clue would be in the error message, which you chose not to disclose.

Comment: Well, you cannot connect to a database if the instance is not started. Make sure you are running the commands (what you want is `db2start`, not `db2stop`) from the DB2 Command Window.

Comment: With db2start I get same error message of db2stop (SQL1390C  The environment variable DB2INSTANCE is not defined or is invalid.)

Comment: Do you run these commands from the `db2cwadmin.bat` with elevated privileges? What appears in the db2diag.log file?